# PHP class to parse and send emails

Tags: php, piping, exim4, email-parsing

I have Exim4 that pipes incoming emails to my PHP script.

This PHP script should parse it, modify some headers and probably add some info like:

> This email was sent by example.com service.

(both plain and html versions).

What I'm looking is a PHP class(es), that can create object to work with from raw email(headers+content+attachements). Email can be plain || html, single part || multipart, gmail-like, etc.

After I finish my manipulations, I should be able to send modified email.

Can you advice me something? Thanks!

I've tried Zend_Mail, but it's not intended for such kind of tasks.

I don't want to write parser myself, I'm quite sure it will be another bicycle.

I would prefer to not use any extensions and avoid any unnecessary configuration changes on the server.

Comment: What was the issue with Zend_Mail? Thats what i would think to use for this task...

Comment: Check http://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/